# Rails: Scope: making a method available to all Views and Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I've struggled with scope for a few days. I would like to have a small number of methods available to ALL Views and Controllers.
Suppose the code is:

```
def login_role
  if current_user
    return current_user.role
  end
  return nil
end
```

If I include it in application_helper.rb, then it's only available to all Views, but not available to all Controllers

If I include it in application_controller.rb, then it's available to all Controllers, but not available to all Views.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Create your own library (it could have classes, modules, methods), and put it in the lib directory. Let's call it my_lib.rb.

In your application_controller.rb, and application_helper.rb add the following line:

```
require 'my_lib'
```

This will make all the classes, modules, methods available to all Views and Controllers

Comment: Files in the `lib` directory are already required by the framework.  You also have to call `include MyLib` in application_controller.rb and application_helper.rb.

Answer (score 31):

Use the [`helper_method`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper) method in your `ApplicationController` to give the views access.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :login_role

  def login_role
    current_user ? current_user.role : nil
  end

end
```

Consider putting all the related methods in their own module then you may make them all available like this:

`helper LoginMethods`

Comment: Where would I put the LoginMethods module?

Comment: Most people put it in `RAILS_ROOT/lib`.

Comment: Any reason why this is better than what I suggested? both suggestions involve adding a library module. Would not using the require save a restart?

Comment: What you're suggesting does not work. If I create a login_method.rb in the lib folder, and include in it a module LoginMethods with all my login methods, and then add helper_method LoginMethods, I get an error message. I restarted the rails server, just in case.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper: `helper_method` works on individual methods. `helper` takes a module as argument.